# Analytical formula for all combinations of n items without repetition where order is not important

Tags: combinatorics

I do have `n` items and would like to get the number of all possible combinations whereby the order can be ignored and repetitions are not allowed.

For example, for `n = 3` I expect

```
x1, 
x2, 
x3,
x1, x2
x1, x3
x2, x3
x1, x2, x3
```

so the number should be `7`.

I can calculate this number, I think, by summing up the binomial coefficients:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$$.

I can calculate this in Python as follows

```
from scipy.special import binom

n = 3
sum(binom(n, k) for k in range(n))
```

which indeed returns `7`.

What I am wondering is whether there is an analytical equation for this. The closest I [could find](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) is

$$\binom{n + r - 1}{r} = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$$,

but that allows for repetition.

Comment: You seem to be trying to count all nonempty subsets of a set, in which case the answer you are looking for would be $2^n - 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: That seems indeed to give the same output as the sum I calculate. Is there a way to derive this formula and if so, could you do it or point me to a place where that is done? Is there a connection between the binomial coefficients and your formula?

Comment: @Cleb I upvoted your query for the level of detail and the nice formatting of the presentation.  That being said, I offer one (very) mild criticism for future reference.  It is important that the poster make it **crystal clear** what he is asking.  Ideally, this clarity will be present at the **start of the query.**  I wasn't sure what  question your query was asking.

Comment: @user2661923: Very good point, thanks for making me aware! When I now read my post again, I also realize that there is no actual question stated but it is rather implicit in the "I am wondering..." part. I will keep it in mind and also update this post later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your example, what you wish to calculate is the number of all nonempty subsets of a set.

Each subset is determined by choosing whether or not to include a particular element.  For instance, if our set is $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, if we choose to include $1$, not include $2$, not include $3$, include $4$, and not include $5$, we obtain the subset $\{1, 4\}$.  For a set with $n$ elements, there are two choices for each element, giving $2^n$ subsets, of which one is the empty set, so there are $2^n - 1$ nonempty subsets of a set with $n$ elements.

The number of subsets with exactly $k$ elements is $\binom{n}{k}$.  Hence, the number of nonempty subsets of a set with $n$ elements is
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n}{0} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} - 1$$

The Binomial Theorem states that
$$(x + y)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{n - k}y^k$$
If we substitute $1$ for both $x$ and $y$, we obtain
$$2^n = (1 + 1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}1^{n - k}1^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} - 1 = 2^n - 1$$